# Which body coordinates Ministries of Magic across the globe?

Tags: harry-potter, government

We know that there are lots of Ministries of Magic across the globe, each representing its nation. Also, we know that the magical laws of each nation aren't the same. For example, flying carpets are illegal in England, but legal in most of the nations in Asia.

However, there are certain laws which are applied worldwide. For example, the *International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy* is in place, I think, across the world.

Is there a *United Nations* type body (maybe, a secret part of the UN itself) which governs international laws in the wizarding world?

Comment: To be honest, there doesn't seem to be any international wizard law structures. Everyone seems to be working on their own brand of control, in each nation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The International Confederation of Wizards would.

The International Confederation of Wizards is the worldwide governing body responsible for coordinating Ministries of Magic, enforcing the laws that wizards worldwide have agreed to. They were responsible for gathering wizards from all nations to reach a consensus on how to hide magical creatures from the Muggles and which creatures to hide.

> “The International Confederation of Wizards argued the matter out at their famous summit meeting of 1692. No fewer than seven weeks of sometimes acrimonious discussion between wizards of all nationalities were devoted to the troublesome question of magical creatures.” 
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

They’re also responsible for ensuring all nations follow international wizarding laws, and the Ministries of Magic ultimately have to answer to the International Confederation of Wizards.

> “In 1750, Clause 73 was inserted in the International Code of Wizarding Secrecy, to which wizard ministries worldwide conform today:
>
> Each wizarding governing body will be responsible for the concealment, care, and control of all magical beasts, beings, and spirits dwelling within its territory’s borders. Should any such creature cause harm to, or draw the notice of, the Muggle community, that nation’s wizarding governing body will be subject to discipline by the International Confederation of Wizards.” 
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

When certain nations end up breaking international wizarding laws, the International Confederation of Wizards can punish the nation, and have done so before.

> “The International Confederation of Wizards has had to fine certain nations repeatedly for contravening Clause 73. Tibet and Scotland are two of the most persistent offenders. Muggle sightings of the yeti have been so numerous that the International Confederation of Wizards felt it necessary to station an International Task Force in the mountains on a permanent basis.” 
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Anything that concerns international wizarding laws, reaching a worldwide agreement on what wizards should do about a situation, or ensuring that nations comply with the laws already decided upon would be done by the International Confederation of Wizards.

Answer (score 26):

[**The International Confederation of Wizards**](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/international-confederation-of-wizards/)

> The International Confederation of Wizards is a wizarding intergovernmental organisation, equivalent to the Muggle United Nations. The leader of the ICW is called the Supreme Mugwump.

---

JK Rowling confirmed this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/630125966606630912)

> **Thu Ya Win:** Is there a wizard UN
>
> **JKR:** The equivalent is the International Confederation of Wizards.

---

The first time the position is named is in *The Philosopher's Stone* when Harry receives his letter from Hogwarts and lists Dumbledore as the Headmaster along with his other titles:

> Headmaster: Albus Dumbledore
> (Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc., Chf. Warlock, Supreme Mugwump, International Confed. of Wizards)

Comment: So Dumbledore was the head of Wizard UN ? 

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  There is an Internantional Confederation of Wizards. It governs the [Ministers for Magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic) and the [wizarding schools](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools) among other things.

> Damocles Rowle
>   1718 - 1726
>   Rowle was elected on a platform of being 'tough on Muggles'. **Censured by the International Confederation of Wizards**, he was eventually forced to step down.
>
> -Pottermore Ministers for Magic
>
> There are eleven long-established and prestigious wizarding schools worldwide, all of which are **registered with the International Confederation of Wizards**.
>
> -Pottermore Wizarding Schools

Answer (score 10):

### The International Confederation of Wizards

> **Is there a wizard UN?**
>   The equivalent is the International Confederation of Wizards.

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/630125966606630912)